# DatePicker Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

My Project is now using DatePicker Component by Ant Design, the format of calendar when click on select field is render by 'MMM' format, I want it use 'MMMM' format.
Example:
Jan -> January

Feb -> Febuary

Mar -> March

Apr -> April

May -> May

Jun -> June
Jul -> July

Aug -> August

...

I need calendar will render month as 'MMMM' format instead of 'MMM' format
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use cellRender prop to customize cell value. `<DatePicker open picker='month' cellRender={(current) => <div>{(current as Dayjs).format('MMMM')}</div>} />`